# IpMsg on windows doesn't display all users

Tags: windows, networking, ip, wifi

We have wifi connection in our office connected with two different routers.

Before the two different wifi router ,IpMsg was working perfectly.
But now It displays only one user ,that is me. Other users are not displayed.

Sometimes it displays all users and sometimes just one user,that is me.

I uninstalled IpMsg,tried newer version ,but no help.

My internet connection is also working .